# Transparent image planes in cycles have strange borders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I get strange borders on my image planes, even if there is a perfect 100% alpha.

[image: Image planes with alpha in a cycles scenery]

The rendered output looks like this:

[image: The border of the image plane is visible]

I know that this problem was once in the old blender renderer due the "premultiply issue", but now I don't see any premultiply option in cycles renderer.

The node setup is the standard "import image planes" for cycles as shadeless:

[image]

Maybe you know a workaround or a setting option in order to fix this?

Comment: Could you post the earth image you are using?

Comment: @Brain can you try making the plane smaller in the UVmap (so it doesn't touch the edges of the picture ) and see if this makes a change

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like there is some aliasing issue with your alpha channel.

I can see two solutions:

Change the texture interpolation from **Linear** to **Closest**.

[image]

If that doesn't work try adding a Math node to the alpha channel and set the mode to Greater than and the value to .5

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the texture interpolation from Linear to Closest solved the problem.

Comment: That was super helpful thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your transparency must be set to absolute white.

Set the color to full white manually, even if it looks white.
Inspect carefully.

You (may)have a default RGB  value of .8, .8, .8

Light Gray may look deceptively like white.

Change to 1.,1.,1.

Picture to follow

Comment: My picture has already a perfect 100% alpha. The problem was solved by the solution provided by cegaton, changing the texture interpolation from Linear to Closest.