# Green screen video has dark outline around object

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image, video, chromakey

### PROBLEM

Hi! I chroma keyed a green screen video in DaVinci Resolve, then imported it with `Image As Plane` into a blender scene as an Emission node so it’s not affected by lights in the scene *(I just change emission strength to match the scene).*

In DaVinci, the key is fine, and there is no weird dark outline. But when imported into Blender, it looks like the following:

[image: Weird dark outline on keyed blender object]

And here's the node tree:

[image: node tree of this problem]

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? The only thing I can think of is that there’s something wrong with the codec I used to export the keyed video from DaVinci, or something’s up with Blender.

And for all this:

- I’m using Blender 2.93, and cycles.
- I set the video’s Material Properties → Viewport Dispaly → Settings → Blend and shadow modes both to Alpha Clip.
- I turned the light paths max bounces all the way up to 5+ for everything. Even though there’s nothing that would get in the way to prevent light from passing through, etc
- I set Light paths → Clamping both to 0.
- I set the alpha in my video’s node in the Shading tab’s N-panel to both Straight, and Premultiplied.
- I messed with every material setting that had a positive value, and it changes nothing.
- In DaVinci, I used the GoPro CineForm RGB-16 bit codec with Alpha export on, and that’s the only codec with an alpha channel available for me on this computer, so I can’t test other options.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the node tree?

Comment: Just added it, and thanks for helping btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fixed it. The problem was my original key.

Originally, I never tested the key against a white background. It was always either transparent or black. Thus, I never saw the dark outline.

Then I fixed the key, imported it into blender, and it worked perfect.