# Image with transparency used as texture shows white line on the edges

Tags: texturing, transparency

The plane object have the bubble text as texture.
The texture have alpha channel, but in the 3d view and the render is generate lines of white color, I don't know why. I wait that you can help me. Thx.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you find those same pixels of white in your image editor, or can you try to use an eraser to eliminate those lines? I ask if they exist before the image is placed into the material texture. Once way is to open it in the UV/Image Editor and the Color and Alpha view will let you see if they are there or if this is a problem with the geometry you have the texture on.

Comment: possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27993/transparent-image-planes-in-cycles-have-strange-borders/28021#28021 As a side note" When asking   a question please specify what render engine you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In the Textures tab scroll down to **Image Mapping** and change Extension to **Clip**.

[image]

Comment: I do this but still the problem persists :(
Edit: In render mode is fix, thx!

Comment: Which render engine are you using, 'Blender Render' or 'Cycles Render'?

Answer (score 2):

The texture is repeating the top and bottom edge pixels. Set the texture's Extension to 'clip' to fix the issue.

[image: Edge pixel repeating vs clipping]

Comment: Thx!, in render mode is fix, in 3d mode the problem persists...