# How to change texture interpolation of many images all at once?

Tags: python, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have imported many images as planes and need to change the texture interpolation from linear to closest to solve an issue similar to this one: [Transparent image planes in cycles have strange borders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27993/transparent-image-planes-in-cycles-have-strange-borders) (although I am on eevee).

[image]

This could be done with python right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to make a node property value the default?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172761/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-node-property-value-the-default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to find all image texture nodes and set their interpolation type to `'Closest'`:

```
import bpy

# Run through all materials of the current blend file
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    # If the material has a node tree
    if mat.node_tree:
        # Run through all nodes
        for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
            # If the node type is texture 
            if node.type == 'TEX_IMAGE':
                # Set the interpolation -> Linear, Closest, Cubic, Smart
                node.interpolation = 'Closest'
```

See: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.html#bpy.types.ShaderNodeTexImage.interpolation

Comment: I got this error:




```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/farid/Gunga/Nature Brasil/animation/cenas1-2-3-4-5.blend/Text", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodes'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Comment: yes, if there are no nodes, the script will fail... add another for loop after `for mat in bpy.data.materials: ` `if mat.use_nodes == True:` .

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181959/92768

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks :)

Comment: If that "fixed it", please consider to accept the answer @FaridAbdelnour How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @brockmann thanks for the edit!

Comment: @brockmann what solved it actually is this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/181959/92768

Comment: Huh, I think the code I've added has a much better explanation @FaridAbdelnour Otherwise you should close it as duplicate.

Comment: @brockmann your explanation is great but I get an error when running it.

Comment: That's fun. What do you think how we can help based on "I get an error"? @FaridAbdelnour ... and again otherwise you can always click on the button to close it as dupe

Comment: @brockmann odd, today it seemed to work. Sorry still getting the hang of this. I will be clearer moving forward.

Comment: No problem @FaridAbdelnour Glad you got it working... Yeah, I'd recommend to communicate at least, we are all just volunteers trying to help each other.